# Accessing a SQL Server database from Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Basic 2010 to write a front end to a database I created in SQL Server 2008. The problem I am having is when trying to add the SQL Server database as a new data source, I get the error message:

> You don't have permission to open this file. Contact the file owner or an administrator to obtain permission

So is this a permission I need to set up in SQL Server to allow the connection from VB? If so, can someone please tell me what this is?

Really stuck with this, hoping to find an answer asap if possible.

Comment: Have u tried to connect to that db from management studio first?

Comment: I suggest to: 1. Check if you have access to DB from management studio (already mentioned by @Kamran Shahid). 2. Run VS with administrator rights and try one more time. 3. Close SQL management studio and try to connect from VS again, because this error can occur when DB's file already in use by management studio. If so, you may ready about changing of AutoClose property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try open your Visual Studio as '**Administrator**' and if it works, then the issue is with Visual studio.

Else it should be with your SQL Server. Try the below steps;

- Right click on your database and choose **Properties** option.
- In the pop up window, go to Option ad change the **auto close** option to true as shown below;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the permission in file for specific user.(Read/Write Access)