# Getting Permission denied error while using sql server data base with entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

while learning Entity Framework using VS2015 Community, I am getting permission denied error while setting up connection to the local database made on the same machine using SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Attaching Screenshot:

[Permission Denied Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdyBb.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593952/accessing-a-sql-server-database-from-visual-studio

Comment: @ZLK thanks I will try the solutions mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but I could not get past that permission error.
Here is what I tried and got through.

While choosing data source, I chose **Microsoft SQL Server** instead of <strike>Microsoft SQL Server Database File</strike>.
Then instead of using . as server name for local server, I used full server name, viz. MyPc\SQLEXPRESS

This populated the database names in the database drop down and connection was made.